# finding $E[X]$ of a exponential distribution with a deductable

Tags: probability, statistics

Losses follow an exponential distribution with parameter $\theta$. For a deductible of 100, the expected payment per loss is 2000. What is the expected payment per loss for a deductible of 500?

They get 
$2,000e^{\frac{-400}{\theta}}$ but I'm not sure how they got this.

I know I need to solve for $\lambda$ so what I did was I transformed the parameter $\theta$ to fit the deductible by subtracting 100. Therefore $Y=\theta-100$. Now to find $E[Y]= \displaystyle\int_{100}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda \theta +100\lambda}=2000$ but the solution doesn't exist. Where did I go wrong?

Following with what Gaffney said, I integrated $\displaystyle\int_{100}^{\infty}(\theta - 100)\lambda e^{-\theta \lambda}$ which I get $\dfrac{-e^{-100\lambda}}{\lambda}=2000$ (since the $-\theta e^{-\theta \lambda} + 100e^{-\theta \lambda}$ will cancel out with 100) substituting 500 gives us $-400e^{-500\lambda} - \dfrac{e^{-500\lambda}}{\lambda}= ?$ which we are trying to figure out but I do not know how to make the connection of the 1st result with the 2nd.

Comment: It looks like you're integrating the pdf, but for expected value you want to integrate the pdf times $(\theta-100)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the loss $X$ is $\lt 100$, then the payment is $0$. If $X\ge 100$, the payment is $X-100$. Thus the expected payment is
$$\int_{100}^\infty (x-100)\frac{1}{\theta} e^{-x/\theta}\,dx.$$
This turns out to be $\theta e^{-100/\theta}$.

Similarly, the expected value of the payment if the deductible is $500$ turns out to be $\theta e^{-500/\theta}$.

Putting $\theta e^{-100/\theta}=2000$ we get the expression given as an answer.

A more complete answer can be given by solving $\theta e^{-100/\theta}=2000$ numerically. We get that $\theta$ is approximately $2097.65$. From this we can find the numerical value of the expected payment with a deductible of $500$.

Comment: why do we multiply by $x-100$? instead of $\theta - 100$ if that is the parameter they gave us? I thought $\theta$ represented the loss amount and, $y=\theta - 100$ is the insurance payment. By the way is $\theta$ your $\lambda$ in this problem?

Comment: Following with what Gaffney said, I integrated $\displaystyle\int_{100}^{\infty}(\theta - 100)\lambda e^{-\theta \lambda}$ which I get $\dfrac{-e^{-100\lambda}}{\lambda}=2000$ (since the $-\theta e^{-\theta \lambda} + 100e^{-\theta \lambda}$ will cancel out with 100) substituting 500 gives us $-400e^{-500\lambda} - \dfrac{e^{-500\lambda}}{\lambda}= ?$ which we are trying to figure out but I do not know how to make the connection of the 1st result with the 2nd.

Comment: If $X\lt 100$, the insurance company pays $0$. If $X\ge 100$, the company pays $X-100$. So expected payment is $\in_{100}^\infity (x-100)\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$, where $\lambda =1/\theta$.

Comment: ok how is $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{\theta}$? How do you get that

Comment: We don't need to use the letter $\lambda$, we can use $\theta$ as in the OP. It looks as if they are using the mean $\theta$ of the exponential as the parameter. That gives density function $\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}$. It is more common to use $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, that is, to let the parameter $\lambda$ be the reciprocal of the mean.

Comment: ahhhh I see how was I suppose to know $\theta$ was the mean that's pretty vague. So the safest way to find the answer is to solve for $\theta$ and plug it into the equation for the 500? no way to do this algebraicly ?

Comment: There **sort of** is a way, using the (non-elementary) Lambert $W$-function. Wolfram Alpha will probably use that. But there is no standard "algebraic" way to solve an equation that mixes exponentials and polynomials. The standard approach for such problems is numerical approximation.